# Executing a script from inside code in VxWorks 6.7

Tags: vxworks

In VxWorks 5.5.1 you could run a script using the execute command.  In VxWorks 6.7 the execute command is no longer supported.  Does anyone now if there is a replacement? I am specifically talking about from inside code not command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through much research it appears like there are a few ways to accomplish this but none is exactly the same as the execute command from before.  As I stated in the comment below it turns out that the execute command is not an official API call.

1) shellCmdExec can be used but most be called from inside the shell task.
2) The solution we choose to employ - which is to call it from within our startup script

3) And a hack way:

fd = open("/y/startup.go", 0, 0) /* open the script you want to execute */
v=shellFromNameGet("tShell0") /* Get the shell i.d. */

/* Use shellinOutGet to save off the standard in of the shell */
shellInOutSet (v, fd, -1, -1) /* Set the standard in of the shell to the file */

/* Here you should restore the standard in (do a shellInOutGet beforehand).   Do it after the shell is done with the script.   I would say that your script should increrment a variable when ti is done.   */

close(fd)

Answer (score 0):

There's a solution in the VxWorks Kernel programmer's guide 6.7, the problem is that it did not work for me, but it could help you:

```
    shellGenericInit ("INTERPRETER=Cmd", 0, NULL, &shellTaskName, FALSE, FALSE,fdScript, STD_OUT, STD_ERR); do
    taskDelay (sysClkRateGet ());
    while (taskNameToId (shellTaskName) != ERROR); close (fdScript);
```

Check Section 15.2.15 of the document.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it in the serial driver layer. Try the following code. It shows how to send text to the shell's input.

For example,

pass_to_sio("memShow; ifconfig"); in your c code.

-> sp pass_to_sio, "memShow; ifconfig" in the shell.

pass_to_sio("< test.scr"); in your c code if you want to run a script file.

-> sp pass_to_sio, "< test.scr" in the shell if you want to run a script file.

```
void pass_to_sio(char *input)
{
    int old_priority;

    taskPriorityGet(taskIdSelf(),&old_priority);

    taskPrioritySet(taskIdSelf(),250); /* task priority must be lower than tShell0 */

    NS16550_CHAN *pChan = &ns16550Chan[0]; /* this line depends on your BSP */

    while (input != NULL && *input != NULL)
    {
        (*pChan->putRcvChar) (pChan->putRcvArg, *input);
        input++;
    }

    (*pChan->putRcvChar) (pChan->putRcvArg, '\r');

    taskPrioritySet(taskIdSelf(),old_priority); 
}
```