# Redirecting to stdin in order to execute script in vxworks 6.7

Tags: vxworks

I need to execute a script in vxWorks 6.7. It can be done with the execute() function in vxworks 5.5. The solution that I am applying is to use stdin redirection as in the following code:

```
    newStdIn = open("myScript.txt",O_RDONLY,0644);
    oldStdIn=ioGlobalStdGet(STD_IN);
    ioGlobalStdSet(STD_IN, newStdIn);
    /*Read file here and execute*/
    ioGlobalStdSet(STD_IN,oldStdIn); /*Restore old stdIn*/
    close(newStdIn);
```

I am missing the read and execute part (where the comment is).

**EDIT:**
According to the vxworks kernel programmers guide, the way to execute a script is as follows:

```
    fdScript = open ("myScript", O_RDONLY);
    shellGenericInit ("INTERPRETER=Cmd", 0, NULL, &shellTaskName, FALSE, FALSE, fdScript, STD_OUT, STD_ERR);
    do
       taskDelay (sysClkRateGet ());
    while (taskNameToId (shellTaskName) != ERROR);
    close (fdScript);
```

But it will open a new shell without processing the script.
The problem with this is that my application won't do anything after calling shellGenericInit.

Comment: You can do it in the serial driver layer. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52863308/10481046

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are starting a Cmd shell, rather than a C Interpreter shell.
Since you mention that you used the execute() function in 5.5, I assume that your script is for the C Interpreter.

Try changing  "INTERPRETER=Cmd" to "INTERPRETER=C".

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I tried that too. The issue I am facing is very specific, as the problem was that shellGenericInit won't work because shell creations has been disabled on our system, it took some time to find out this. Thanks again.