# How to write and execute shell script from code in vxworks 5.5?

Tags: shell, vxworks

I've been digging a lot for an answer on how to do this. The only clue i've found is that there exists an `execute()` function which is mentioned in these questions, and that it was never officially a supported API call:
[Redirecting to stdin in order to execute script in vxworks 6.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25529269/redirecting-to-stdin-in-order-to-execute-script-in-vxworks-6-7)
[Executing a script from inside code in VxWorks 6.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909979/executing-a-script-from-inside-code-in-vxworks-6-7)

I would really like to know which library to include and how to use this `execute()` function or alternately another way of executing shellcommands or scripts from code in vxworks 5.5

Answer (score 1):

Never heard about execute(), but the best way to learn is to teach :)

Obviously execute() function is a part of [shellLib](http://www.vxdev.com/docs/vx55man/vxworks/ref/shellLib.html). API list makes impression of being unfinished, so my guessing is that VxWorks devs didn't consider shellLib done or tested thus hiding execute().

I played a bit with this function and usage is straight forward: it accepts array of chars, parses it and executes. I bet, "target shell" feature in VxWorks is based on calling execute() for each line of user input.

Since you consider function to be unofficial, I don't expect anyone to appear in topic with clear documentation, so the best advice is to try it by yourself.

Comment: Surely it's a bit of an odd thing to do in the first place? All that a 'shell' script does is to call various functions that have been included in the image or dynamically loaded, and calling them is more easily accomplished from within one's C/C++ code. Just my two pennies worth...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the serial driver layer. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52863308/10481046